# Install4j Command Line Compiler with -D options containing white spaces and quotes

Tags: install4j

I'm trying to build my application using the install4J command line compiler (install4jc).

I want to pass some variables to the compiler, using the -D NAME=VALUE syntax.

Here is my command:

```
install4jc -r myVersion -D application.fullName="my Full Name",application.shortName="my Short Name" projectFile.install4j
```

When I execute that command I get the following:

```
install4j: too many arguments 
Usage: install4jc [OPTIONS] [config file]
Try 'install4jc --help for more information'
```

If I remove the application.shortName="my Short Name" like this:

```
install4jc -r myVersion -D application.fullName="my Full Name" projectFile.install4j
```

it works.

Why can't I use multiple options with quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This quoting style does not work with install4j, use:

```
-D "application.fullName=my Full Name,application.shortName=my Short Name"
```

instead.